# How do I check if my laptop WiFi supports 5ghz feq

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 
I wanna check if my laptop supports 5ghz Freq because it is unable to search for my 5ghz freq
I attached the screenshot of available channels=>
[Available channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAY86.png)

Comment: Get the info for your card - `lspci | grep -i network` - share what model card you have.  Or, look up the card online to see if it's dual band capable (dual band means it also supports 5Ghz)

Comment: @ThomasWard I think it's `lspci`.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen it is - but that was simply a small typo thanks to me typing fast on a phone without autocorrect :P

Answer (score 7):

You can check the channels that your wireless card supports with the terminal command:

```
sudo iwlist chan
```

Please note that setting your regulatory domain may affect the usable channels. In case yours is unset, here is the procedure:

Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Now check again:

```
sudo iwlist chan
```

Comment: WiFi is still unable to search for 5ghz freq

Comment: Does it scan at all? `sudo iwlist scan` What channel is the desired access point on? It is, by any chance, above 124?

Comment: Now i checked and found Freq is above 5.64

Comment: So it won't work. But Thanks for Help @chili555